# Need help with a vertical mount, male A USB connector

Tags: pcb, usb, connector, surface-mount, manufacturing

I need to figure out a way to get a Male A USB connector to vertically attach to a PCB. Ideally, we wouldn't use a surface mount right angle connector.

[image: Need the opposite of this!]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Most of the male connectors are right angle SMT which would require an extra step in our assembly (and more labor).

Comment: Have you though about mounting in a small adapter pcb, then mounting that with right angles?

Answer (score 3):

I think the image at the top is cut from our page (-:

We offer a male full size A right angle PCB mounting connector here:  http://gct.co/connector/?series=USB1061

There is a micro version, vertical, however that is Micro B. http://gct.co/connector/?series=USB3150   this is at preliminary

I look after the USB product range at GCT and am not familiar with any manufacturers offering a vertical A plug in full size, the main reason is that male vertical connectors are normally used for docking/cradle type applications, where a device would be plugged to a dock to charge and transfer data. These applications require high mating cycles. The full size USB2.0 A connectors (plug and socket) are normally only good for 1,500 cycles, which is below the mating cycle requirement for most cradle mount applications. So in turn connector manufacturers didn't developed these options due to commercially viability.  That's why you can find the micro vertical plug types on the market, but not 'full size'.

Hope that helps to explain why you can't easily find what you're looking for.  It does not help too much, you might need to consider switching from full size USB2.0 to Micro USB2.0 to achieve your physical design.

All the best
Laurence

Answer (score 1):

This link may give you some help: [Vertical USB connector, what is the best practice?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23342/vertical-usb-connector-what-is-the-best-practice).

I think it's difficult to directly mount a right angle USB A connector vertically on PCB. One method is mounting the connector on a small PCB as normal, then using some other sockets to connect this small PCB to your major one. However, this need more extra work. Why not choose a vertical type directly? And there are indeed USB A Type Vertical Single type connector, such as: http://www.cypressindustries.com/usb-a-type-connector-vertical.html.

---

Update:

Sorry for the mistake I've made. The OP wants a "male" USB A connector, vertical mounting and not SMT type. I've never seen such a product. Can you accept some "converters", such as [USB Male to Female 90-Degree Connector](http://www.miniinthebox.com/usb-male-to-female-90-degree-connector_p1202783.html)  or [USB Male to USB Male Connector](http://www.miniinthebox.com/usb-male-to-usb-male-connector_p1202774.html). Then you may have more choices on your PCB mounting connector, but these need more money and spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! We need a male connector though which makes that Cypress part not a great fit. Any other products you know out there?

Answer (score 1):

It actually exists, only in China:

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/USB-3-0-A-Male-PCB_62313017196.html

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/USB-2-0-A-Male-PCB_62259048167.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those do not look like right-angle SMT connectors to me...there is no contact that would lie flat against the PCB. I think these are intended for edge mounting parallel to the board.